# another strange behaviour with GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek

Take a look at the piece of code bellow:

```
Calendar today1 = Calendar.getInstance();
today1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
System.out.println(today1.getTime());

Calendar today2 = new GregorianCalendar(2010, Calendar.JULY, 14);
today2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
System.out.println(today2.getTime());
```

I'm quite confused... Assuming I am running it today as July 14th, 2010, the output is:

```
Fri Jul 16 14:23:23 PDT 2010
Wed Jul 14 00:00:00 PDT 2010
```

The most annoying thing is that if I add today2.getTimeInMillis() (or any other get() method) it will produce consistent result. For the code bellow:

```
Calendar today2 = new GregorianCalendar(2010, Calendar.JULY, 14);
today2.getTimeInMillis();
today2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
System.out.println(today2.getTime());
```

The result is:

```
Fri Jul 16 00:00:00 PDT 2010
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is actually documented in the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for `java.util.Calendar`

Quoted here:

> set(f, value) changes calendar field f to value. In addition, it sets an internal member variable to indicate that calendar field f has been changed. Although field f is changed
>   immediately, the calendar's
>   milliseconds is not recomputed until
>   the next call to get(), getTime(), or
>   getTimeInMillis() is made.

So that explains the behavior you are seeing, but I concur with another responder to your question that you should consider [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) if you're going to do a lot of Date coding.

Comment: `Calendar` is indeed lazily loaded, but this doesn't *actually* explain the problem. Why doesn't it work with `new GregorianCalendar(y, m, d)` but does it work with `set(y, m, d)`?

Comment: Yes, it does explain.

It's because with GregorianCalendar(y, m, d) you have no WEEK_OF_YEAR computed yet. While with set(y, m, d) you have first called Calendar.getInstance() which gives us an object with all fields filled up.

Answer (score 2):

You should in fact be using `Calendar#getInstance()` to get an instance and not `new GregorianCalendar()`. Replace that line by

```
Calendar today2 = Calendar.getInstance();
today2.set(2010, Calendar.JULY, 14);
```

and it will go well.

Sorry, no detailed explanation for the behaviour, expect that `Calendar` along with `java.util.Date` are one of the major epic failures in the current Java SE API. If you're doing intensive date/time operations, then I'd recommend to have a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). The upcoming new Java 7 will ship with an improved date/time API based on JodaTime ([JSR-310](https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/)).

Answer (score 0):

*(Sorry for the edit, I wanted this to be a little more readable, but couldn't get it right when I originally wrote the answer...now it's essay length, but there you go...)*

Just to add to what's already been said, the issue arises from the returned `Calendar` instances being prepared differently. I personally feel like this is a design flaw, but there may be good reason for it.

When you call `Calendar.getInstance()`, it creates a new `GregorianCalendar` using the default constructor. This constructor calls `setCurrentTimeMillis(time)` with the current system time, and then calls the protected method `complete()`.

However, when you create a new `GregorianCalendar` using the constructor that you did, `complete()` is never called; instead, among other things, only `set(field, value)` is called for the various bits of information that is provided. This is all well and good, but it has some confusing consequences.

When `complete()` is called in the first case, the member variables dustmachine alluded to are checked to determine what information should be recalculated. This results in a branch that forces calculation all of the fields (`DAY`, `WEEK_OF_MONTH`, etc.). Note that `Calendar` is indeed lazy; it just happens that using this method of instantiation forces an explicit recalculation (or in this case initial calculation) on the spot.

So, what impact does this have? Given that no upfront field computation was performed in the case of the second object creation, the two objects have vastly different states. The first has all of its field information populated, while the second only has the information which you provided. When you call the various `get*()` methods, it shouldn't matter, because any changes should provoke the lazy recalculation step when you retrieve the information. However, the order in which this recalculation occurs exposes the differences between the two varying initial states.

In your particular case, this is due to the following relevant code in `computeTime()`, which is necessarily invoked to compute the correct time when you request it with `getTime()`:

```
boolean weekMonthSet = isSet[WEEK_OF_MONTH] || isSet[DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH];
...
boolean useDate = isSet[DATE];

if (useDate && (lastDateFieldSet == DAY_OF_WEEK
      || lastDateFieldSet == WEEK_OF_MONTH
      || lastDateFieldSet == DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)) {
    useDate = !(isSet[DAY_OF_WEEK] && weekMonthSet);
}
```

In the first case, all fields are set due to that initial calculation. This allows `weekMonthSet` to be true, which, along with the `DAY_OF_WEEK` that you provided in your call to `set(field, value)` being set, causes `useDate` to be false.

However, in the second case, as no fields have been calculated, the only fields set are the ones you provided in the constructor and in the subsequent `set(field, value)` call. Thus, `useDate` will remain true, because `isSet[DATE]` is true per your constructor, but `weekMonthSet` is false as the other fields in the object have not been computed anywhere, nor set by you.

When `useDate` is true, as implied, it uses your date information to generate the value for the time. When `useDate` is false, it's able to use your `DAY_OF_WEEK` information to compute the time you expect, resulting in the difference you see.

Finally, this raises the question of why calling `getTimeInMillis()` before calling `getTime()` will fix the unexpected behaviour. As it turns out, the fields *will* be recalculated as a result of your `set(field, value)` call in both objects. This just happens to occur *after* the time is calculated, for whatever (probably genuine) reason. Therefore, forcing the time to be calculated once on the second `Calendar` will essentially align the states of the two objects. After that, I believe the calls to `get*()` should all work consistently for both objects.

Ideally, the constructor you used in the second case should perform this initial calculation step in the name of consistency (although maybe for reasons of performance this wouldn't be preferred), but it doesn't, and this is what you get.

So, in short, as the others mentioned, [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is your friend, and clearly these classes are less so. :)